# NSTextView and NSAttributedString

Tags: cocoa, nstextview, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to stick an attributed string into my NSTextView, but it's just showing as plain text, no attributes.  I created my string like so:

```
    NSString *str = @"Parsing Directory Structure\n\n";

NSMutableAttributedString *attrstr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [NSColor blueColor],
                             NSFontAttributeName : [NSFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:20.f]
                             };
[attrstr setAttributes:attributes range:NSRangeFromString(str)];

[[self.textView textStorage] appendAttributedString:attrstr];
```

and on the NSTextView (inside the scrolling view) I've got the "Allows Rich Text" box checked still, and the Editable box unchecked.  I'm basically trying to use this like a console output window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSMakeRangeFromString` parses a textual representation of a range, it doesn’t create a range which covers a string. As your text contains no integers it returns the range `{0, 0}` - location and length both zero. So therefore your text is not styled.

Replace with `NSMakeRange(0, str.length)` and your code should work.